# Apache Spark fails to connect to MonetDB Cluster using JDBC Driver

Tags: jdbc, apache-spark, monetdb

We have problems connecting to a MonetDB Cluster via Apache Spark using JDBC.
Connection to a database that is not clustered works. But when we try to connect to a clustered MonetDB database via Apache Spark, it fails with a "unhandled result type error". The entire query is given below

We have tried plain JDBC to connect to a monetdb cluster and it works. Only Spark fails.

```
val v1 = hiveContext.load("jdbc",Map("url" -> "jdbc:monetdb://1.1.1.1/tpch1?user=monetdb&password=monetdb","dbtable" -> "(select count(*) from customer)v1"))
**java.sql.SQLException: node */tpch/1/monet returned unhandled result type**

java.sql.SQLException: node */tpch/2/monet returned unhandled result type
        at nl.cwi.monetdb.jdbc.MonetConnection$ResponseList.executeQuery(MonetConnection.java:2536)
        at nl.cwi.monetdb.jdbc.MonetConnection$ResponseList.processQuery(MonetConnection.java:2284)
        at nl.cwi.monetdb.jdbc.MonetStatement.internalExecute(MonetStatement.java:508)
        at nl.cwi.monetdb.jdbc.MonetStatement.execute(MonetStatement.java:349)
        at nl.cwi.monetdb.jdbc.MonetPreparedStatement.<init>(MonetPreparedStatement.java:118)
        at nl.cwi.monetdb.jdbc.MonetConnection.prepareStatement(MonetConnection.java:901)
        at nl.cwi.monetdb.jdbc.MonetConnection.prepareStatement(MonetConnection.java:825)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.DefaultSource.createRelation(JDBCRelation.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ddl.scala:290)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.load(SQLContext.scala:679)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:23)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:28)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:30)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:32)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:34)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:36)
        at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:38)
        at $iwC.<init>(<console>:40)
        at <init>(<console>:42)
        at .<init>(<console>:46)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1338)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:856)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:901)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:813)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:656)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:664)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:669)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:996)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:944)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:944)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:944)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1058)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

> RD 1429856293844: read final block: 67 bytes RX 1429856293845:
>   bwnthqobupI3CPY:merovingian:9:RIPEMD160,SHA256,SHA1,MD5:LIT:SHA512: RD
>   1429856293845: inserting prompt TD 1429856293846: write final block:
>   99 bytes TX 1429856293846:
>   BIG:merovingian:{SHA256}7070477fd396595c929386453a32ac5059a9b76976e54dab3fbb7a8f5299bd25:sql:tpch1:
>   RD 1429856293847: read final block: 0 bytes RX 1429856293847:  RD
>   1429856293847: inserting prompt TD 1429856293847: write final block:
>   49 bytes TX 1429856293847: sSET TIME ZONE INTERVAL '+05:30' HOUR TO
>   MINUTE ; RD 1429856293848: read final block: 3 bytes RX 1429856293848:
>   &3
>
> RD 1429856293848: inserting prompt TD 1429856293855: write final
>   block: 15 bytes TX 1429856293855: Xreply_size 250 RD 1429856293855:
>   read final block: 0 bytes RX 1429856293855:  RD 1429856293855:
>   inserting prompt TD 1429856293855: write final block: 68 bytes TX
>   1429856293855: sPREPARE SELECT * FROM (select count(*) from
>   customer)v1 WHERE 1=0 ; RD 1429856293856: read final block: 52 bytes
>   RX 1429856293856: !node */tpch/2/monet returned unhandled result type
>
> RD 1429856293856: inserting prompt

Comment: Do you have a full stack trace?

Comment: Thanks for your help Hannes. I have updated the post with full stack trace. Only cluster with multiplex funnel is a problem. There is no problem connecting to a single node.

Comment: If you connect with the extra parameter debug=1 (e.g. in your case `jdbc:monetdb://1.1.1.1/tpch1?user=monetdb&password=monetdb&debug=1`, the JDBC driver will produce a .log file with some helpful debug info. Perhaps you could share this output as well.

Comment: I tried with debug=1. No log file got created. Where does it get created?. I searched for recently created files after i ran the Spark job. I looked in the same directory as the JDBC folder, MonetDB folder as well as var/logs

Comment: Not sure where this file ends up in your spark setup, but the filename is `monet_1429855366161.log`, where the number is a timestamp.  Also a correction, the parameter value should be `true`, not `1`. So `debug=true`.

Comment: Added the log as an update in the original post

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies not with JDBC, but with the merovingian funnel. It seems the funnel does not like the statement `PREPARE SELECT * FROM (select count(*) from customer)v1 WHERE 1=0 ;` See whether you can keep your application from using prepared statements. Feel free to file a bug report on this at http://bugs.monetdb.org

Comment: Its not we, but Spark that prepares the statement and sends it. So we cant do anything. Can you please let me know if this will be fixed ?